# calculate the repeatence of combinations elements in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations

suppose I have two vector like this :

```
l1 = c('C','D','E','F')
l2 = c('G','C','D','F')
```

I generate all combinations of two elements using `combn` function:

```
l1_vector = t(combn(l1,2))
l2_vector = t(combn(l2,2))

> l1_vector
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "C"  "D" 
[2,] "C"  "E" 
[3,] "C"  "F" 
[4,] "D"  "E" 
[5,] "D"  "F" 
[6,] "E"  "F" 

> l2_vector
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "G"  "C" 
[2,] "G"  "D" 
[3,] "G"  "F" 
[4,] "C"  "D" 
[5,] "C"  "F" 
[6,] "D"  "F"
```

Now I want to calculate the repeat elements of `l1_vector` and `l2_vector` , as the example i give, the repeat of elements should be 3 `(["C","D"],["C","F"],["D","F"])`

How can I do that without using loop ?

Comment: `merge(l1_vector, l2_vector)`?

Comment: Jota,that work ! Really a nice trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [`merge`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/merge) function for this. Since the default behavior of `merge` is to use **all** of the available columns, it will return only those rows that are perfect matches.

```
> merge(l1_vector, l2_vector)
  V1 V2
1  C  D
2  C  F
3  D  F
> 
> nrow(merge(l1_vector, l2_vector))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

While `merge` is perfectly fine for your case, there is some work around.

If you just need the number of repeated elements:

```
choose(length(intersect(l1, l2)), 2)
[1] 3
```

If you need the repeated elements:

```
t(combn(intersect(l1, l2), 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "C"  "D" 
[2,] "C"  "F" 
[3,] "D"  "F"
```